# How do I properly use the FolderBrowserDialog in Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

So I'm still fairly new to Powershell and I'm trying to write a script that allows the user to select a file or folder and then get back the security permissions for said folder/file. The problem is, I can't seem to get the file path to record as a variable to be used later. Here's what I have so far:

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.ShowDialog()

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm way off on this, but it will pull up the window to select a file or folder and makes me choose twice and then doesn't set the variable as the file path. Again, I'm pretty new to this kind of thing so I could be totally wrong, but any help would be incredibly helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

The folder selector window shows twice because you have two calls to `$foldername.ShowDialog()`. Remove the first one, and leave only the one inside `if`.

I tried to run your code, and am sure that `$folder` variable is in fact set. If you think that it is not set you are doing something wrong. For example, be aware, that it is only visible inside your `Get-Folder` function. If you need to use it outside of the function, you should return it (`return $folder`) and assign it to a variable outside the function. For example:

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="")

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$a = Get-Folder
```

This way you will have your selected folder in the `$a` variable.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution that opens dialog window, asking user to select a folder.  Then stores the folder path inside a variable named "path":

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$null = $browser.ShowDialog()
$path = $browser.SelectedPath
```

Answer (score 10):

## Selecting a folder

Using `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` allows you to select a folder only.

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory) {
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $FolderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
    if ($initialDirectory) { $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory }
    [void] $FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath
}
($FolderPermissions = Get-Folder C:\Users | get-acl | select -exp access | ft)
```

For more info on `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` class check [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog).

## Selecting a file

```
function Get-File($initialDirectory) {   
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    if ($initialDirectory) { $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory }
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = 'All files (*.*)|*.*'
    [void] $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}
($FilePermissions = Get-File C:\ | get-acl | select -exp access | ft)
```

For more info on `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` class check [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog).

Answer (score 5):

You need to add " | Out-Null" to the end of the line
"[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")"

otherwise there is a bunch of info returned by Get-Folder you don't want

Cheers, Garth

Answer (score 1):

very old but if somebody needs this:
The dialog pops up in the background.
You can use the ShowDialog(owner) overloaded methode like this to show the dialog at TopMost:

```
$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
$foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

$modalform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$modalform.TopMost = $true

if($foldername.ShowDialog($modalform) -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
} else {
    # no folder selected
    # do something
    Exit
}
return $folder
```

This creates a new form, sets this at TopMost and the ShowDialog method will use this topmost window as the owner. As a result the dialog box will shown also as the topmost window.
All other properties will not work as i tried them like "Modal", "TopLevel" and so on...

Answer (score -3):

Just add the following line somewhere in the Function before the 'ShowDialog()' line:

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow  "`n`n`t* * * `t`tW A R N I N G :   Dialog box may be hidden behind another [or this] window!!!`t`t* * *"
```

Comment: While testing the script, I found two irritants:
1. It always opens behind the PowerShell window I’m using (hence the warning above).
2. If I’m using the line $FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer', and sending ‘$initialDirectory’ to the function, if the desired folder isn’t near the top of My Computer, it’s off-screen.  My initial reaction was that it didn’t select anything; until my brain finally caught up & said, “scroll down.”  (12 hour shifts; I’m tired  )
Commenting-out the ‘.RootFolder’ didn’t make a difference.

Comment: So your answer is the solution to your own question/problem - defined in a comment of your own answer - and not directly an answer to the question in the original post? I think this would do better as a stand alone post with a reference to this question.