# How do I export a CSV file with a list of all the names contained in the folder?

Tags: powershell, csv

I wish to create a script to pass on to a user which asks for the file path location and exports all the names of the files contained within it into a CSV,the dir must be the folder.

```
# set the variable $FilePathLocation to whatever the user specifies
$FilePathLocation = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the path location you wish to export'

# set the working directory
Set-Location $FilePathLocation 

# select the names of all the content in the folder and pop it in to a CSV file within the location
dir -Recurse | Select Name | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File "test.csv"
```

Prompt:

```
Please enter the path location you wish to export: "C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Depositions going into trial bundle"
```

Error:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At line:3 char:1
+ Set-Location $FilePathLocation
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: Did you use `"` or `'` in your path? Try it without, just C:\bla\bla

Comment: Your computer doesn't have a drive `"C:` (note the leading double quote in the error message). Enter the path without double quotes, or remove leading/trailing double quotes after the path was entered.

Comment: Opps, my bad, it was the ", i tries it without the speach marks and it works great.

Thanks guys

Comment: & also how do i make the export display or have some sort of indication of content within sub folders as its currently just a flat list of items @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: `Select Name` -> `Select FullName`. Also, use `Export-Csv` instead of `ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File`. `Get-ChildItem $FilePathLocation -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv 'test.csv' -NoType`

Comment: Thanks again @AnsgarWiechers, but is there any way i can make the Names of the Sub folders stand out a little more?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: If this script is for regular non-technical users, you might consider prompting for the folder using a folder browser dialog like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690038/how-do-i-properly-use-the-folderbrowserdialog-in-powershell

Comment: @Khalifa96 A CSV can't be formatted. If you want the output in the console to stand out more, read this: [Write PowerShell Output in Color Without Using Write-Host](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-write-powershell-output-in-color-without-using-write-host/)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$directoryName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the directory to create a file listing csv for"
if(Test-Path $directoryName -PathType Container) {
  $csvPath = Join-Path -Path $directoryName -ChildPath "depositions.csv"
  Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryName -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation
  "Your file has been created at: {0}" -f $csvPath
} else {
  "{0} is not a directory.  Please enter a directory when prompted." -f $directoryName | Write-Warning
}
```

Comment: Is there any way possible of clearly indicating the sub folders without having to read the file path names?, maybe a spacing between the lines or bold characters for the folder names?

Comment: @Khalifa96 CSV is a plain text format. Formatting values is not possible. What you can do is export directory and filename as separate fields: `Select DirectoryName, Name`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Thats much better thank you v much

Comment: @phiz This answer also has nothing to do with the question that was asked (despite the OP moving the target in the comments). The question describes a problem caused by a simple typographic mistake in the text that was entered at the prompt, and should thus be deleted.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't subscribe to your opinion.  My answer 1) exports a csv with the names contained in the folder 2) asks for the file path location and 3) verifies the input is a folder.  The OP's answer to their own question mirrors mine.

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to do the trick.

```
$FilePathLocation = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the path location you wish to export'

Set-Location $FilePathLocation 


Get-ChildItem $FilePathLocation -Recurse | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name | Export-Csv 'FileNames.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to set a location, just query the full path name for the file list

```
$FileList = dir -recurse $FilePathLocation
$FileList | Select Name | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\test.csv'
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't address the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: Maybe not, but pretty sure it's the result he's looking for

Comment: The code the OP is using would do the same. Again, that's not the problem at hand. Please read the error message and my comment to the question.