# Dialog for browsing and select folders

Tags: powershell, winforms, dialog

In order to render more user-friendly my script I would like to load a dialog in which a complete folder tree (from the C:\ root) is browsable and where I could select multiple (sub)folders through check boxes. How can I accomplish such task?

P.S.: the best solution should also include hidden folders

Edit: after the evaluation of the comments and the early reply I will clarify what I am looking for. I would like to create a dialog in which the folder tree is showed, where I can expand or collapse the branches and where I can select parent folders and/or some of the children/leaves (subfolders and/or files) at the same time.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25690038/11942268

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly use the FolderBrowserDialog in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690038/how-do-i-properly-use-the-folderbrowserdialog-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

By using `New-object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` and change
`$FormOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = $False` to `True` you have a File-browser that can select several folders.

```
$FormOpenFileDialog = New-object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$FormOpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = ""
$FormOpenFileDialog.Title = "" 
$FormOpenFileDialog.Filter = ""
$FormOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = $True
$FormOpenFileDialog.showHelp = $true
$FormOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

$ApplicationForm.Controls.Add($FormOpenFileDialog)
```

By Adding this to a Form, binded to a button maby is the best solution ?

```
$ApplicationForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$BtnOpenFileDialog = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$BtnOpenFileDialog.text= "Open Folder"   
$BtnOpenFileDialog.location = "50,50" 
$BtnOpenFileDialog.size = "80,20"  
$BtnOpenFileDialog.Add_Click({ GenerateFormOpenFileDialog }) 
$ApplicationForm.Controls.Add($BtnOpenFileDialog) 
function GenerateFormOpenFileDialog { # Start GenerateFormOpenFileDialog

$FormOpenFileDialog = New-object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$FormOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = ""
$FormOpenFileDialog.Title = "" 
$FormOpenFileDialog.Filter = ""
$FormOpenFileDialog.Multiselect = $True
$FormOpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
$FormOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()


} # End GenerateFormOpenFileDialog


# Initlize the form
$ApplicationForm.Add_Shown({$ApplicationForm.Activate()})
[void] $ApplicationForm.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

***Why Filebrowser and not folderbrowserdialog ?***

folderbrowserdialog has more limitations.

[FileBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0)

[FolderBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=net-5.0)

If you want to create a form, Sapians has a great forum for this.
https://www.sapien.com/
https://www.sapien.com/forums/

Comment: This does help the OP because `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` does not allow you to select folders.